# a tighter upper bound for $\left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2 - 1}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Actually, I am looking for a tighter upper bound for $(1+\frac{1}{n^2 - 1})^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \frac{n}{n+1}$. It is easy to prove $(1+\frac{1}{n^2 - 1})^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \frac{n}{n+1} < e^{-\frac{1}{n+1}}$. But I find $(1+\frac{1}{n^2 - 1})^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \frac{n}{n+1}$ can be bounded by $e^{-\frac{1}{n}}$. So I am looking for some ideas to prove this bound.

Comment: Its quit simple actually as we know limₓ-> a ( f(x)^g(x)) can be treated as lim ( f( x)) and lim( g(x)) individually. So just apply limits individually to both the functions and 1/(n^2-1) becomes 0 as it's 1/(infinity) therefore u get f(X) = 1 and now (n-1)/2 tends to infinity therefore g(X) tends to infinity. Thus by simple logic u could say that the given limit can simplified as 1^(infinity) and any exponent to 1 always gives 1.

Answer (score 1):

If $$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)^{g(x)} \rightarrow 1^{\infty},$$ then $$L=\exp[\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) (f(x)-1)].$$So here $$ L=\exp [\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{n-1}{2} \frac{1}{n^2-1}]= \exp[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2(n+1)}]=e^0=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

For the general case we can use that

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n}=\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\right]^\frac1n$$

then recall that by $k=n^2 \to \infty$

- $\left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)^{k}\to e$

and for the particular one, since $n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2-1}\right)^{\frac{n-1}2}=\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2-1}\right)^{n^2-1}\right]^\frac1{2(n+1)}$$

As an alternative for the general case we have by $\log (1+x)\le x$

- $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n}=e^{n\log \left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)}\le e^\frac1n$

and by [**Bernoulli inequality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)

- $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n} \ge 1+\frac1n$

and therefore

$$1+\frac1n \le \left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n}\le e^\frac1n$$

from which we can conclude by squeeze theorem.

Comment: Is there any tighter upper bound for $(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^n$?

Comment: @Icy we have that $$(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^n=e^{n\log (1+\frac{1}{n^2})} \le e^{1/n}$$

Comment: @Icy I add something on that approach.

Comment: by using this method, I can only prove that $ ((\frac{n}{n+1})^{n+1} (\frac{n}{n-1})^{n-1}) < e^{-\frac{1}{n+1}}$. But I want to prove that $((\frac{n}{n+1})^{n+1} (\frac{n}{n-1})^{n-1}) < e^{-\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: @Icy I see now you have completely changed the original question. It's not fine. You should rollback to the original and ask a new question.